# Unable to connect to SQL Server from a docker container

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

We have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application that worked with its backend database hosted on a separate server perfectly. All CRUD operations worked flawlessly. We dockerized the application but we started getting the following error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

The docker compose file looks like the following code:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  services.webapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}serviceswebapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services.WebApi\Dockerfile
      network: host
```

What may be wrong in this configuration hindering the application to communicate with the SQL Server instance?

**UPDATE 1**: the SQL Server is not dockerized.

**UPDATE 2**: The application reads the SQL connection string from its appsettings.json file. This is the connection string after renaming the server name and credentials:

```
Server=WIN-MSSQL1\\MSSQLSERVER2017;Initial Catalog=ServiceDB;User ID=cruduser;Password=foo;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

Comment: it is that the complete compose file or more service? The SQL is dockerized also?

Comment: Yes, that's the complete compose file. The SQL server is not dockerized.

Comment: How the dockerized application know how to reach the SQL service? I mean in a configuration file have the hostname of SQL server? if yes you can try to add an additional host in the hosts file of the docker with option: 'extra_hosts:
 - "somehost:162.242.195.82"'

Comment: Please see update 2 in the question where I posted the connection string.

Comment: Just to confirm: are you able to use that exact same connection string in a console app outside of docker and confirm the connection works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a normal situation you could fix by adding the sql hostname in the /etc/hosts file of the container via composer file like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  services.webapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}serviceswebapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services.WebApi\Dockerfile
      network: host
    extra_hosts:
      - "WIN_MSSQL1:192.168.0.1"
```

Unfortunately due this [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1455) adding the extra_hosts in the composer file will not work, I hope they fix the issue soon.

So to let connection work substitute the hostname with the ip address of SQL server:

from this:

```
Server=WIN-MSSQL1\\MSSQLSERVER2017;Initial Catalog=ServiceDB;User ID=cruduser;Password=foo;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

to this:

```
Server=192.168.0.1\\MSSQLSERVER2017;Initial Catalog=ServiceDB;User ID=cruduser;Password=foo;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

Comment: But the server name is WIN-MSSQL1, right? WIN-MSSQL1\\MSSQLSERVER2017 is the alias. Then shouldn't the extra host be like the following entry?
    extra_hosts:
      - "WIN_MSSQL1:192.168.0.1"

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work! I am wondering what else may be required in this configuration!

Comment: if you go inside the container you able to ping the SQL host? "docker exec -it 'container_name' ping WIN_MSSQL1

Comment: Just pinged the IP address of the server 192.168.x.x and it did not reach out to the server!

Comment: I find this issue https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1455 docker run on windows host?

Comment: Yes, it's running on Windows.

Comment: may not very beatiful solution but try to change the hostname with the ip address in the connection string, like this we could determinate if the issue is the name resolution or have some thing else.

Comment: Not sure if it's going to help because pinging the IP address of 192.168.1.2 which is SQL Server's from within the container did not work.

Comment: Ok, I got it, I'm driving home now, have you try to use the docker bridge instead network: host (just remove the line network: host) and try to pinging again the sql server by his ip address

Comment: I switched the docker to bridge mode but it was not conclusive either.

Comment: Sorry this looking very strange, from the host machine you can ping the sql host?

Comment: I am unable to ping from the host machine because I realized the remote SQL Server blocks ping requests.

Comment: I replaced the machine name with ip address in database connection string in appsettings.json file and it worked while network set to host in the docker compose file. I removed extra_host to be concise.

Comment: Well, I'm happy to eat that, so if was not for the issue on docker for windows the solution I proposed to you works.

Comment: I insert the information we get from the issue founded in github and the workaroun applied in the answer.

Comment: Please feel free to update your answer per the comment that I voted for and I will mark it as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, @Arash I modified the answer as per the comments, please review the connection string.