# Not able to connect to host database from asp.net core application which is in docker windows container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

Not able to connect to host sql database from asp.net core application which is in docker windows container

I have given host connection string with username and password but it is not connecting.

The connection string is as follows:

```
Server=<ip address>,<port>;Database=<database>;Integrated Security=False;User Id=<id>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

The error message I am getting is as follows:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Answer (score 0):

If the SQL server is running on the same host (i.e. the same machine) as the Docker container, you can use the special host name `host.docker.internal` inside the container to reach "`localhost`" on the host machine.

In other words: `host.docker.internal` inside the container points to `localhost` outside the container.

If both of them are running in containers, remember to make sure the SQL Server container publishes the correct ports (using the `-p` flag).

Comment: Thanks Jon for your reply. I have apis running in container which are trying to connect to MSSQL database instance hosted in my machine. As per your inputs I have updated the connectionstring property in appsettings.json file to: "ConnectionString": "Server=host.docker.internal;Database=DemoDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" . I did a validation and now I am getting error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.

Comment: Any help on this is much appreciated :)

Comment: Bit uncertain. I don't have any experience with MSSQL specifically. Are you sure it's connecting on the correct port?

Comment: yes it is running on port number 1433, can it be some firewall issue?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, Docker usually handles all that. The only thing I can think of is to test whether you're able to reach the MSSQL container from the Web API container using [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/). Also, you might want to look at this previous answer which also talks about MSSQL in Docker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008489/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-from-a-docker-container?rq=1